# How do you restore a DB to Multi-User mode when deadlocked by a sys process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database that is stuck in Single User mode after a failed restore process. I have checked the sysprocesses table and none of the processes have spid > 50. They are all sa processes. Using the following code returns a deadlock that I can not seem to clear:

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET MULTI_USER with NO_WAIT
```

Besides restarting the SQL Server and then spamming the Alter statement, is there a way for me to pull this out of single user mode? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Possible option that I have never tried: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dfurman/archive/2012/01/20/getting-out-of-single-user-mode.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what Shawan referenced, another option is to use DAC `ADMIN:ServerName`

then issue below command (note that I am not using NO_WAIT)

```
ALTER DATABASE database SET MULTI_USER with rollback immediate
```

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) :

> **ROLLBACK AFTER integer [SECONDS] | ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE**
>
> Specifies whether to roll back after the specified number of seconds or immediately.
>
> **NO_WAIT**
>
> Specifies that if the requested database state or option change cannot complete immediately without waiting for transactions to commit or roll back on their own, the request will fail.

Comment: Connecting using DAC worked. I was able to execute the ALTER statement without issue after that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Judicator Glad that could help out!